# Custom traits through rest service

Tags: magnolia

We have a requirement of  custom traits and the data for the custom trait should be fetched from our rest API.

Examples for traits we are looking into are like :  Balance, Currency, Birthday etc.(Should be dynamic).

Business wants the ability to add a new custom trait from the configuration, with the data available from the rest api.
In case if we add new data items in the rest api we should be able to configure and use that custom trait corresponding to that data.

For this requirement,

I had gone through the Silver pop & Sugar CRM modules, 
It seems like complexity involved to understand the login and external forms.

I have added some generic class implementation. But still I am  not able to populate the traits in the Magnolia with data from rest.

I need few more clarifications regarding this.

1.How Magnolia recognizes the trait. Through Configuration/ something else(XML)?

2.If I try to generate the configuration with the static values in the version handler and called register methods by passing the tasks as parameters in the constructor. But still I am unable to see the trait configuration in the admin central.(config.modules.rest-traits-module.traits.balance.xml, config.modules.rest-traits-module.traits.currency.xml). Can we generate this kind of configuration as dynamic in Java code?

3.How can we set labels for the Traits instead of adding in Properties file? because we need them as dynamic.

4.Can we generate dynamic yaml files through java?(For traits configuration) If yes, does it support for Magnolia 5.3.9?

5. In the silver pop module they given some external form and its actions.. In my requirement i am not using any external forms? How can I proceed?
6. Does login is mandatory for this requirement?

Could you please suggest.

Thanks for your support,

--Vijay Kodali.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.How Magnolia recognizes the trait.

You register the trait in the `traits` folder under your module. [See documentation on creating custom traits](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Creating+custom+traits) for more info.

> 2. Can we generate this kind of configuration as dynamic in Java code?

Yes you can. Perhaps you made mistake somewhere in your version handler? Or it was not called because your module is already installed? Hard to say without seeing the code.

> 3.How can we set labels for the Traits instead of adding in Properties file? because we need them as dynamic.

not really "trait specific", but general Magnolia/Vaadin UI question. If you want to set labels dynamically, you would need to write your own FormPresenter (or View) implementation.

> 4.Can we generate dynamic yaml files through java?(For traits configuration) If yes, does it support for Magnolia 5.3.9?

Yes, you can generate yaml files through java. It doesn't matter what/whom puts them in filesystem as long as they are on observed file path.
And no, you can't register traits via yaml (yet) no matter which version of Magnolia you use. And in general yaml support is since 5.4 only, so it would not work on 5.3.9 anyway.

> 5. In my requirement i am not using any external forms? How can I proceed?

Traits have no direct connection to external forms. Those two are independent feature. In silverpop/marketing-cloud module they were used together since Magnolia was both producing data for Silverpop and consuming data from it, but you can have custom traits even without external forms. For more details see the above mentioned [documentation on creation of custom traits](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Creating+custom+traits).

> 6. Does login is mandatory for this requirement?

No login is not mandatory.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan.May I know the complete structure of data for trait returning by the rest service?

Comment: For your service? It doesn't matter. All trait class does is calling service and passing on some data ( cookie in case of silverpop) to identify value of whatever user trait is this class representing. Try to replicate example from documentation with user-agent. There you see trait ( users browser) directly from value. In your case you most likely want to call rest service and pass on whatever data that service needs to give you info about the user.